# Group by no longer works when switching to MS Sql Server / TinyTds

Tags: ruby-on-rails, tiny-tds

I just migrated a rails app from SQLLite to MS Sql Server. I had a group by that was working fine under SqlLite but is giving an error as follows when using the SQL / TinyTds.

```
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid in Complaints#report_by_product
Showing C:/Users/cmendla/RubymineProjects/internal_complaints/app/views/complaints/report_by_product.html.erb where line #10 raised:

TinyTds::Error: Column 'ic.complaints.id' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.: EXEC sp_executesql N'SELECT [ic].[complaints].* FROM [ic].[complaints] GROUP BY [ic].[complaints].[product_name]'
Rails.root: C:/Users/cmendla/RubymineProjects/internal_complaints

Application Trace | Framework Trace | Full Trace
app/views/complaints/report_by_product.html.erb:10:in `_app_views_complaints_report_by_product_html_erb___717152080_78192168'
app/controllers/complaints_controller.rb:18:in `report_by_product'
```

The by product def in the complaints controller is

def report_by_product

```
@complaints = Complaint.all
@complaints_group = Complaint.group("product_name")         # causes the report to be grouped by the product

respond_to do |format|
  format.html
  format.json { render json: @complaints }
end
```

end

A portion of the by products view is

```
  <tr>
    <% @complaints_group.each do |complaint_group| %>

        <% $complaint_group_name = complaint_group.product_name %>
    <td>
      <%= complaint_group.product_name %>
    </td>
    <td style="text-align: right;">
      <%= (Complaint.where("product_name like ?", $complaint_group_name )).count %>
    </td>
    <td style="text-align: right;" >
      <%= (Complaint.where("product_name like ?
                            AND complaints.created_at > ?",
                           $complaint_group_name, Date.today-360).count) %>
    </td>
        <td style="text-align: right;">
          <%= (Complaint.where("product_name like ?
                            AND complaints.created_at > ?
                            AND complaints.created_at < ? ",
                               $complaint_group_name,
                               Date.today-90,
                               Date.today).count) %>
```

My TDS gems are

```
Installing activerecord-sqlserver-adapter 4.2.8 (was 4.2.4)
Using tiny_tds 0.7.0
```

Answer (score 1):

I got this working. I had to change the grouping statement in my controller.

from:

```
 @complaints_group = Complaint.group("product_name")
```

To:

```
   @complaints_group = Complaint.select("product_name").group("product_name")
```

That got it working properly.